# How can i insert break lines on the text "Something to break" in multiple lines?

Tags: html, css

[image: Here is a specific screen of the code with the result]

You can see that I tried to put

```
<div class="periodic-element intense-work" data-description="Something<div>To</div></br>Break">
</div>
```

But it didn't work.

[Here full code on Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qb1kdx6f/1/)

Thanks for helping !

Comment: You have to set the data description to the div's innerhtml on hover using javascript.

Comment: I will try to do that, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Javascript as @rguttersohn mentioned, but to do this within your current CSS framework, you'll need to change the `content` property on your `.periodic-element:after` selector and make a change to your html element.

`<div class="periodic-element intense-work" data-description="Something" data-description-2="To" data-description-3="Break">`

Notice the addition of `data-description-2` and `data-description-3`. In the CSS you'll need to add

`content: attr(data-description) "\A" attr(data-description-2) "\A" attr(data-description-3);`

AND

`white-space: pre-wrap;`

This will concatenate the different data-description attributes into so many lines. See the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lhb8sqo/).

Comment: Thank you for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I just found an easier way to do that :

I add; `white-space:pre-wrap;` to `.periodic-element:after`

then I used `&#010;` in my text.

https://jsfiddle.net/2jy8pnLg/

And alternatively, just pressing ENTER to create new lines worked too.

https://jsfiddle.net/2jy8pnLg/1/